# Running a ruby cron job

Tags: cron

I was trying to create a cron job which runs a ruby code on digital ocean, however it seems I'm making a mistake. It doesn't give any error but it doesn't also do anything. I ran this cronjob on my raspberry pi however on digital ocean it doesn't work. Here my cronjob

```
59 17 * * * ruby /home/workspace/delta/analytics/analyze.rb 7 >> /home/testruby
```

It creates testruby file but analyze.rb 7 doesn't work. I tested running ruby /home/ .... and it is working. What might be the problem?

**UPDATE**

error file: bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/ruby: not found

This is what I wrote in my crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/ruby /home/workspace/deriva/analytics/analyze.rb 7 >> /home/testruby 2>&1
```

Comment: There error is a little odd, was there a `/` in front (`/bin/sh:…`)? Anyway, are you sure that is the right path to Ruby? `ls -l /usr/local/bin/ruby` shows it? What about `command -v ruby`?

Comment: @derobert Well, the command that you wrote shows the actual directory of ruby. After giving it, it started to work. Mine is     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different environment variables, working directory, ... You need to debug where exactly analyze.rb is bailing out.

First, you're only redirecting stdout, not stderr. Errors probably go to the later, so adding a `2>&1` to the end may help a lot. Or setting `EMAIL=` at the top of your crontab to have them mailed to you.

You can confirm that ruby is starting up the `print "starting!\n"` or similar to the beginning of your Ruby script, and seeing if that shows up in the log file.

Comment: Thank you, I added what you said, it gives the error "ruby not found". How can this happen? I run the same code on the command line and it is working

Comment: @AhmetTanakol Different $PATH. You can fix by using the full path to ruby or putting a PATH= line at the top of the crontab.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to give full path to ruby but still same error. I will search it

Comment: @AhmetTanakol please edit your question to include the new crontab (with the full path to ruby) and the exact error message produced.

Comment: I updated my question with the error message.